# Inner html div doesn't behave width the expected width

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm building a personal page for myself, using react and libraries such as styled components, for react. But when I was building the header section, all of a sudden the content started not to behave as expected, with the inner div not matching its parent's width anymore. Here goes the codes:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const SectionContainer = styled.section`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
`
```

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { SectionContainer } from '../components/SectionContainer'

const Container = styled.div`
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap');

    @media (min-width: 501px) {
        img {
            width: 500px;
            height: 550px;
        }
    }

    @media (max-width: 500px) {
        img {
            width: 70%
            min-width: 300px;
            height: 70%
        }
    }

    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px inset;
    overflow: hidden;

    h1 {
        font-size: 2.8rem;
        padding-top: 50px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

    h2 {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        font-size: 1rem;
        padding: 0 10px;
    }

`

const Header = props => {
    return (
        <SectionContainer>
            <Container className='header'>
                    <h1>Eduardo Soares Dutra</h1>
                    <h2>Estudante de Ciência da Computação | Desenvolvedor front-end</h2>
                    <img src="src\media\Code typing-bro.svg" alt="Front-end Dev" />
            </Container>
        </SectionContainer>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see here it looks like you have specified that for any devices with a min-width of 501px or more the width of the Container is set to 500px.

@media (min-width: 501px) {
img {
***width: 500px;***
height: 550px;
}
}

So that would override the parent container based on my understanding.